# Adaptive Payment Api Paypal [Peer to Peer]

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am trying to integrate Paypal's Adaptive Payment API into my app with will be only using the peer to peer transactions but I can't do anything related to peer to peer payments. I tried using this tool  [from Paypal](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_simple_payment/)  but I still haven't got any success. Through that Paypal tool, I tried sending money to my one personal sandbox account to my other personal sandbox account but it is still charging me `[3% + $0.30]` (paypal's standard business-client transaction fee).

So, I just want to be able to send money to friends/family through my app using peer to peer transactions that are without any fees. Therefore, my question is how can integrate Adaptive Payment API for only peer to peer payment transaction?

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you talk to PayPal as the first line on https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/adaptive-payments/ states that `It is restricted to select partners for approved use cases and should not be used for new integrations without guidance from PayPal.` I suspect that to test it they will need to enable something on the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to get PayPal's business account to the get the access of their API. I recently talked to their tech support and they let me know that there is no way you can get the API where you don't have to pay the transaction fees.